# Too many redirections on nginx

Tags: nginx

I configured my virtualhost as:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.cc www.example.cc;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name www.example.cc;
return 301 https://example.cc$request_uri;
ssl_keys location_of_keys
}
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name example.cc;
root root_dir;
ssl_keys location_of_keys;

... so on

}
```

I configured it this way so it forces to use https (with http2) and convert www to root. However webbrowser returns with error too many redirections. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using valet and there is the same 'bug' when sharing the url using ngrok. The solution for that is comment out the first 4 lines. Probably it stays in a loop from http to https,but not sure why and how, but that fixed the problem on my machine

Comment: What should I comment out then?

Comment: Found the solution. It was do to cloudflare's cdn solution. Disabled it, and works like a charm. Thanks. Btw, any ideas on using cdn and letsencrypt ssl?

Comment: In what context exactly? I know cdn and letsencrypt, but what do you want to know?

Comment: The cdn and ssl from cloudflare conflicts with my server's own ssl connection (I think). Do you know the solution to this conflict? I disabled the cdn and ssl feature(can only be controlled together) and it works.

Comment: Hm no I'm not that familiar with those two combined together.

Comment: But maybe this post is helpful for you: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/i-have-installed-lets-encrypt-ssl-can-i-use-cloudflare-with-it/12690

Answer (score 0):

I'm using valet and there is the same 'bug' when sharing the url using ngrok. The solution for that is comment out the first 4 lines. Probably it stays in a loop from http to https,but not sure why and how, but that fixed the problem on my machine

```
#server {
#listen 80;
#server_name example.cc www.example.cc;
#return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
#}
```

Edit: I see the first server block returns `https` on port 80, which will maybe cause the problem in your situation, try to comment out the part described above, or else change the return https to http